# find the k smallest\biggest element in a 2D sorted array

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

Given a 2 D array. The rows and columns are sorted.

Find the kth largest element from the 2-d array in most efficient way. Can it be done in-place?

Comment: The title of your question differs from what you ask in the text. Find the _k_-th largest element or the _k_ largest elements?

Comment: How efficient does it need to be? There's no point busting your brains trying to do more than necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly bruteforce in-place solution: try to guess the value by binary search. You know the max and min values (they are in the corners). For every candidate, count the number of elements that are smaller while you follow the boundary between smaller and greater elements. Since the array is sorted, this boundary is a reasonably short path crossing it. Keep track of the position of the maximum among the smaller elements. This value might appear several times. Count them. Assuming an NxN array, this would take O(N*B), where B is the number of bits of the values.

I'm just thinking out loud... I vaguely remember reading about an incredibly optimal solution, but I don't know where.